# Azure Neo4j v4 LOAD CSV with URL not recognizing file

Tags: azure, neo4j, azure-blob-storage, load-csv

I'm using Neo4j v 4.0.3 on Azure. Python code is used to load the database. Standard cypher create queries work as expected:

```
Create (n:xxx{name:'xxx'})
```

However, this does not work:

```
LOAD CSV With HEADERS FROM 'https://neo4jclusterdiag.blob.core.windows.net/neo4j-import/jTags.csv?{SAS}' AS line FIELDTERMINATOR '|' MERGE (p:AncestryTag{TagId: toInteger(line.TagId),color:toString(line.Color),Label:toString(line.Label)})
```

The CSV is simple:

```
TagId|Color|Label
1000|#6ba410|Brydie Scotland
1001|#FFE300|Scroggie
1002|#e3720f|Brodie Scotland
1003|#f06158|Robertson Scotland
1004|#cb478a|Goolsby
1005|#655586|Watt Aberdeenshire
1006|#0079a3|Milne Scotland
1007|#489b9b|Hay Aberdeenshire
1008|#FFB800|Anderson
1009|#a94500|Thomas
1010|#871a13|Bain, McBain
```

I have a separate local install on Neo4j v 4.0.3 and the LOAD CSV works fine there. So it's something amiss with the Azure database.

I've made the following changes in the config file:

```
#dbms.directories.import=/var/lib/neo4j/import
dbms.security.allow_csv_import_from_file_urls=true
```

I try running the LOAD CSV from python code or within the Neo4j browser. Same error with both:

```
neobolt.exceptions.ClientError: Couldn't load the external resource at: https://neo4jclusterdiag.blob.core.windows.net/neo4j-import/jTags.csv?{SAS}
```

In the browser I also see:

```
Neo.ClientError.Statement.ExternalResourceFailed
```

I can place this in my browser address window and retrieve the file:

```
https://neo4jclusterdiag.blob.core.windows.net/neo4j-import/jTags.csv?{SAS}
```

Thus, there is something specifically wrong with my Azure database not recornizing the file I'm trying to import using load csv.

Comment: BTW, I should mention that this code worked with an Azure Neo4j 3.x database. I'm upgrading to 4.x to leverage its multiple database capabilities.

Comment: I don't understand the relevance of mentioning it's your "Azure database." Installing Neo4j on Azure (presumably in a set of VMs?) isn't any different from installing to local VMs/machines, aside from how you manage your inbound/outbound networking ports. That said: You mentioned this all worked in v3.x but not v4.x. Seems like that might be more relevant...

Comment: I have installs of 4.x locally and on Azure (a VM). The former executes the load csv successfully, the Azure install does not. It's not a 3.x vs 4.x issue, but Azure vs local

Comment: There is one difference between the local and Azure Neo4j v 4.x. The local install is the community edition and on Azure it is Enterprise. The latter has 2 dbs at present; perhaps that is the issue?

Comment: A complete guess but maybe the curly braces in the URL are throwing off Neo4j's parsing of the LOAD CSV command. Try changing `{SAS}` to `%7BSAS%7D` and see if that works

Comment: {SAS} was a placeholder for the SAS security string necessary to access the file at Azure. With it appended, I can access the file remotely from my laptop. So that is not the problem.